# Springboot testcontainers fail on kubernetes Jenkins pipeline

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins-pipeline, testcontainers

I am running my **jenkins on kubernetes** with following configuration

Kubernets version : 1.21

jenkins docker image : jenkins/jenkins:2.263.3

Kubernetes plugin : kubernetes:1.30.0

Springboot : 1.5.18.RELEASE

and testcontainer maven dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
  <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
  <version>1.15.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>1.15.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.zonky.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>embedded-database-spring-test</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.flywaydb.flyway-test-extensions</groupId>
  <artifactId>flyway-spring-test</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Springboot test class annotated with

```
@org.junit.runner.RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
@org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc
@io.zonky.test.db.AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase

public class MyTest{}
```

When I run this test on local machine it works fine.

But when similar test gets run on Jenkins pod it is giving following error

```
2021-07-18;09:26:13.161;prefetching-1;ERROR;o.t.u.ResourceReaper;Timed out waiting for Ryuk container to start. Ryuk's logs:
2021/07/18 09:25:13 Pinging Docker...
2021/07/18 09:25:13 Docker daemon is available!
2021/07/18 09:25:13 Starting on port 8080...
2021/07/18 09:25:13 Started!
panic: Timed out waiting for the initial connection

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /go/src/github.com/testcontainers/moby-ryuk/main.go:104 +0xce7

2021-07-18;09:26:13.180;main;ERROR;i.z.t.d.p.FlywayEmbeddedPostgresDataSourceFactoryBean;Unexpected error during the initialization of embedded database
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
    at io.zonky.test.db.flyway.DefaultFlywayDataSourceContext.lambda$reload$0(DefaultFlywayDataSourceContext.java:113)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompletion.claim(CompletableFuture.java:529)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:599)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApplyStage(CompletableFuture.java:617)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenApplyAsync(CompletableFuture.java:1993)
    at io.zonky.test.db.flyway.DefaultFlywayDataSourceContext.reload(DefaultFlywayDataSourceContext.java:106)
    at io.zonky.test.db.postgres.FlywayEmbeddedPostgresDataSourceFactoryBean.postProcessBeforeInitialization(FlywayEmbeddedPostgresDataSourceFactoryBean.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1623)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:121)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:383)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:344)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:417)
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2214)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4053)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4057)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4986)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4992)
    at io.zonky.test.db.provider.impl.DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider.getDatabase(DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider.java:92)
    at io.zonky.test.db.provider.impl.PrefetchingDatabaseProvider$PrefetchingTask.lambda$new$0(PrefetchingDatabaseProvider.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at io.zonky.test.db.provider.impl.PrefetchingDatabaseProvider$PrefetchingTask.run(PrefetchingDatabaseProvider.java:259)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:331)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:312)
    at io.zonky.test.db.provider.impl.DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider$DatabaseInstance.<init>(DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider.java:155)
    at io.zonky.test.db.provider.impl.DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider$DatabaseInstance.<init>(DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider.java:111)
    at io.zonky.test.db.provider.impl.DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider$1.load(DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider.java:60)
    at io.zonky.test.db.provider.impl.DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider$1.load(DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider.java:58)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3628)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2336)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2295)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2208)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerFetchException: Can't get Docker image: RemoteDockerImage(imageName=postgres:10.7-alpine, imagePullPolicy=DefaultPullPolicy())
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.getDockerImageName(GenericContainer.java:1282)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.logger(GenericContainer.java:616)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:321)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not connect to Ryuk at localhost:49157
    at org.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper.start(ResourceReaper.java:171)
    at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:201)
    at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.getDockerClient(LazyDockerClient.java:14)
    at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.listImagesCmd(LazyDockerClient.java:12)
    at org.testcontainers.images.LocalImagesCache.maybeInitCache(LocalImagesCache.java:68)
    at org.testcontainers.images.LocalImagesCache.get(LocalImagesCache.java:32)
    at org.testcontainers.images.AbstractImagePullPolicy.shouldPull(AbstractImagePullPolicy.java:18)
    at org.testcontainers.images.RemoteDockerImage.resolve(RemoteDockerImage.java:65)
    at org.testcontainers.images.RemoteDockerImage.resolve(RemoteDockerImage.java:26)
    at org.testcontainers.utility.LazyFuture.getResolvedValue(LazyFuture.java:17)
    at org.testcontainers.utility.LazyFuture.get(LazyFuture.java:39)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.getDockerImageName(GenericContainer.java:1280)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
2021-07-18;09:26:13.299;main;ERROR;o.s.b.SpringApplication;Application startup failed
```

I found one interesting exception line as below.

```
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerFetchException: Can't get Docker image: RemoteDockerImage(imageName=postgres:10.7-alpine, imagePullPolicy=DefaultPullPolicy())
```

**Update 1:**
I was running my Jenkins on kubernetes 1.21 version,

### After downgrading the kubernetes version 1.19 its working fine.

Does anyone know why it was failing on 1.21 and not on 1.19 ?

Thanks
Alpesh

Comment: Based on the error message, it looks like your tests are reaching out to Postgres database, "Could not connect to Ryuk at localhost:49153". You have to mock your dependencies when you are running unit tests. In case you want to connect to the real database cluster, you have to deploy a database cluster and make sure its reachable from your pod.

Comment: So basically, testcontainer and zonky are used to create docker container for postgresql database which can be used by springboot test, This code is already working on local without creating any explicit database.

Comment: are you able to ssh on to your jenkins machine while it is running your tests and inspect the `Ryuk` docker container? You can then compare that to what you see locally. Is there any noticeable difference between local and jenkins?

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen I am using Kubernetes so I can go inside the running pod. I am adding few more details in my question, please check update1